# Number of edges in Turán graph

Tags: graph-theory, extremal-graph-theory

I am trying to prove that the number of edges in the Turán graph $T^r(n)$ (that is, the complete $r$-partite graph on $n$ vertices whose partition sets differ in size by at most 1) satisfy the inequality
$$|E(T^r(n))| \geq (1-\frac{1}{r} - o(1))\frac{n^2}{2},$$
and I'm stuck. Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: I guess $o(1)$ means $o(1)$ as $n\to\infty$ with $r$ fixed?

Comment: This is my understanding as well, but I am still stuck on how to prove it.

Comment: I think it follows from $|E(T^r(n))|\ge(1-\frac1r)\binom n2$ which follow from the fact that each vertex $v$ of $T^r(n)$ has degree $\ge(1-\frac1r)(n-1)$.

Comment: There is a result in Bollobas' Modern Graph Theory which states that the number of edges of $T^r(n)$ is $(1-\frac{1}{r}+o(1))\binom{n}{2}$, but the result I am trying to prove has $\frac{n^2}{2}$ instead of $\binom{n}{2}$, that's another thing that confuses me.

Comment: $\binom n2=(1-\frac1n)\frac{n^2}2=(1-o(1))\frac{n^2}2$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I recall that the number $|E(T^r(n))|$ can be easily calculated exactly. Let $n=qr+s$, where $0\le s<r$. Then the $r$-partition of the vertex set of the graph $T^r(n)$ has $s$ parts of size $q+1$ and $r-s$ parts of size $q$. Thus

$$|E(T^r(n))|={s \choose 2}(q+1)^2+s(r-s)q(q+1)+ {r-s \choose 2}q^2=\frac 12\left( q^2r^2-q^2r+2sqr-2sq+s^2-s\right)=\frac 12\left(n^2-q(n+s)-s\right)= \frac 12\left(n^2-\frac {(n-s)(n+s)}{r}-s\right)= \frac 12\left(n^2-\frac {(n^2-s^2)}{r}-s\right).$$

Thus 
$$\left|E(T^r(n))|-\frac{n^2}{2}\left(1-\frac 1r\right)\right|=\frac{s(r-s)}{2r}\le \left(\frac {s+r-s}2\right)^2\frac 1{2r}=\frac r8.$$

Comment: But how can I derive from this that 
$|E(T^r(n))| \geq (1-\frac{1}{r}-o(1)) \frac{n^2}{2}$?

Comment: Since $r$ is fixed, we have  even $|E(T^r(n))|=\left (1-\frac 1r+O\left(\frac 1{n^2}\right)\right)\frac {n^2}{2}.$